How would you Improve the Smoothness of a 12V DC Motor Drive with Limited PWM Frequency?
I am developing a control system for a 12VDC brushed motor rated at 500W, which is part of a larger project. Currently, I'm using PWM for motor control, but I'm restricted to a maximum frequency of 800 Hz. The motor is under a heavy load, and this frequency limit is proving to be a challenge.

I've conducted a simulation in LTspice, analyzing the following:

Current through capacitor C3
Current through diode D1
The voltage across motor terminals (N001, N002)
Motor current (x1)



The simulation colour codes represent different duty cycles: 10% (green), 50% (blue), and 90% (red). A concerning observation from the simulation is that the motor current drops to zero during every cycle, indicating inefficiency in the drive mechanism.
Given my minuscule experience with MOSFETs and DC motors, and after some research, I've considered a couple of approaches to address this:

Increasing Frequency: However, my PLC limits the PWM frequency to 800 Hz. Would using a frequency multiplier be a viable solution, or would it be too costly?
Increasing Capacitance of C3: Ideally, the capacitor should be at least 3000 µF and non-polarized. However, it is hard if not impossible to find such a capacitor.
Increasing Inductance: Adding more inductance could theoretically smooth out the current, but handling 60-70 amps with such an inductor might be prohibitively expensive.

Are these approaches valid given the constraints? Are there alternative strategies or improvements I might consider to enhance the smoothness of the motor drive?

Have you considered putting an MCU on the output of the PLC to read off the duty cycle and output the same at a higher frequency, preferably with a MOSFET driver on the same board?

Did you take the inductance of the motor into considferation in your simulation. If that is not enough you can put an inductor in series with the motor... (and btw: please draw your schematic with source left and load right side, makes it much easier to read)

Why would you expect current to not fall to zero during each cycle? The only thing keeping current flowing (via D1) when the MOSFET is off, is motor inductance.

@winny MCU: Indeed, and honestly, that seems like the best solution. However, it introduces additional tasks that I was hoping to avoid due to time constraints. It looks like I might have to build a board eventually though.

@kruemi Inductance: Yes, I did check with the motor manufacturer regarding the inductance. It appears quite low (190 µH + 1.16 mH for mechanical inertia), but I must admit I'm not entirely confident in my ability to assess its sufficiency. Is adding an extra inductor a common practice in such situations? (Note taken!)

@SimonFitch Expected Current: I would appreciate more insight on this topic from someone with deeper knowledge than me. My understanding is that the motor operates more efficiently under a constant current rather than a fluctuating one. Fluctuating currents seem to cause more heat in both the MOSFET and the motor, leading to stronger current surges and increased wear on components. For example, at the moment my system generates way more heat (on MOSFET) on low-duty cycles (5-30%) than on high-duty cycles (70-95%) which doesn't suit well for my application.

@Mark inductances are very common filtering elements in PWM applications (almost any switching regulator)... Let me write an (incomplete) answer, there I can give a schematic too

A board or a big filter. Pick your poison...

Current going to zero (or if you're using an H-bridge even negative) is not really a problem since the resistive losses are commonly pretty low in motor applications.
About your circuit: get rid of the C. It will kill your MOSFET pretty quickly. Because when switching on, the C basically acts like a short in the first moment. FET don't like shorts.
So what you want is:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The values of the components are chosen pretty randomly. You'll have to calculate/select them for your application. You might find more information about that in this answer.
You can also insert a C but make sure, that it's only discharged via the inductance and that you're not getting in trouble with resonant frequencies.

Thanks! That is a good insight and I wouldn't have thought that C might have been the reason that killed one of my FETs. With new knowledge even more questions arise, perhaps you could elaborate or give a reference.
As you mentioned I could insert a C but why should I consider adding it? C1 is there to stabilize the voltage drop but what would make me consider adding one parallel to D1? Would that make the motor more responsive?

@Mark What we're basically building here is a filter. A low pass filter in this case. Adding a C can improve the filter characteristics but honestly: I don't think we'll need that here. Except if you're going for maximum responsiveness. The bigger you make Lfilter, the lower the cut off frequency goes and the smoother your current in the motor will be but that's at the cost of dynamic response. If you go to higher order filtering, you're getting the filter effect without scarifying so much dynamic... If that's a concern...
